# Replacing every 'a' for '&'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that replaces every 'a' for '&'.I am currently stumped and was wondering if someone could write it for me to get an idea of what it would look like. Thanks.

Comment: You might have better luck learning that [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
strw = "kabhi kabhi mery dil main khyaal aata hy"
print (strw.replace("a", "&"))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I appreciate it greatly.